# Feed RSS and <author> tag with fake emails

Tags: rss, atom-feed

In the feed rss I can add the tag .

But to add it I have to add **also** an email.

For example

```
  <item>
    <title>My RSS</title>
    <link>https://www.mywebsite.com/xml/xml_rss.asp</link>
    <description>Item One</description>
    <author>mark@mywebsite.com (Mark)</author>
  </item>
```

**i can not add ONLY the name of the author but it requiered also the email. So...What happens if I add a fake email?**

P.s. I already know that with atom system I can add also only the name, but I prefer to use the "rss way"

Answer (score 0):

> What happens if I add a fake email?

I don't think there are any surprises here: if a client uses that email address to contact the author, the message won't arrive.

If the email address is syntactically valid, and a plausible value, people may use it without realising this.

Providing an invalid value just to make the feed syntactically valid isn't always a good idea. It may be better to omit the field.